# Why does this string not work with ast.literal_eval

Tags: python, string, eval

I get a malformed string error.

Here is my testings

```
>>> eval("'Hello:: '+'fdsfds'")
'Hello:: fdsfds'
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("'Hello:: '+'fdsfds'")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    ast.literal_eval("'Hello:: '+'fdsfds'")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

Comment: I think ast checks if it can be exec'd ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the `ast.literal_eval` [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

Concatenation using `+` isn't included within that: it's not a literal expression, it's a call to `str.__add__`. It's the same reason `1+1` or `"hello".upper()` wouldn't work.

Comment: So basically `literal_eval` is utterly useless.

Comment: simple ast.literal_eval("randomalphabets") also throws "malformed node or string: <ast.Name object at 0x104a3d6d0>" error, with Python 3.9.2.