# Why is this throwing a malformed string?

Tags: python

I am trying to parse a really simple json string in python but am getting a malformed string error. I know that it is a type string (see below), so this is not the problem [Why does this string not work with ast.literal_eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080197/why-does-this-string-not-work-with-ast-literal-eval)

Why else might I get this error? How can I fix it?

```
g = "{\"RequestType\":\"1\" , \"FileName\":\"" + "test" + "\" }"
print type(g)  //prints string
d = ast.literal_eval(json.loads(g))  //throws malformed string error
```

Comment: Also, save yourself the trouble of all the quoting and just use docstrings with formatting. E.g. `''' { "RequestType": "1" }'''`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the link you included contains the following quote: "Concatenation using + isn't included within that: it's not a literal expression".  Isn't that what you're doing in your declaration of the "g string" (huehuehue).  You have a concatenation by +... that wouldn't fly if I'm reading it correctly.

Comment: @mastashake57 but wouldn'y that concatenation happen once the g is created? Then the concatenation is done?

Comment: When `g` is a string, `json.loads(g)` usually isn't. You're checking the type of the wrong thing. In general, when you have a problem like this, break your complex expression down into separate expressions, assign each value to a temporary variable, and then you can explore each of those temporary variables. Like: `obj = json.loads(g)`, then `d = ast.literal_eval(obj)`. Then you can see which of those two lines fails. And `print type(obj)` and see your problem.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean... good point then yes... I would presume that concatenation is done at that point.

Comment: @abe3: Yes, the concatenation is evaluated in creating the `g` value, so `g` doesn't have any `+` character in it. (You can verify that with `print g`.) So mastashake57's comment is a red herring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`json.loads` returns a dictionary, not a string.  Presumably that's what you want, so you don't need `literal_eval` at all; just use `json.loads(g)` by itself.  Or you could use `ast.literal_eval(g)` by itself.  The point is you only need one of the functions, not both, since they do more or less the same thing.